# Is it possible to use sparkline with gt?

Tags: r, formattable, gt

I would like to use `sparkline` mini charts with `gt`'s package table. Is it possible? I know it is possible with `formattable`, but I would prefer to use `gt` tables. Here is what I want to accomplish and how to do it with `formattable`.

[image: sparkline in formattable]

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sparkline)
library(htmlwidgets) 
library(formattable)

set.seed(27)

tibble(
  name = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 20),
  value = runif(40, min = -10, max = 10) %>% cumsum()
) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise(
    chart = spk_chr(
      value, 
      type="line")
  ) %>%
  formattable(align=c("l")) %>% 
  as.htmlwidget() %>% 
  spk_add_deps()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `fmt_markdown` to treat the column as HTML.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sparkline)
library(gt)

p <- tibble(
  name = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 20),
  value = runif(40, min = -10, max = 10) %>% cumsum()
) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise(
    chart = spk_chr(
      value,
      type="line")
  ) %>%
  gt() %>%
  fmt_markdown(columns = vars(chart))
```

Then, add the dependencies using `htmltools::attachDependencies`

```
p_html <- gt:::as.tags.gt_tbl(p)

p_html <- htmltools::attachDependencies(p_html, htmlwidgets::getDependency("sparkline"))

print(p_html, browse = interactive())
```

[image: sparklines]

Comment: Is it possible to save this as a self-contained html?

Comment: @Jakub.Novotny `htmltools::save_html(p_html, "charts.html")`

Comment: I went with that, but it saved the js code in separate folders. If I move the html file, it will not work anymore.

Comment: `cat(repr::repr_html(p_html), file = "charts.html")` should work. Also in the RStudio Viewer, `Export -> Save as Web Page...`

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a lot. You are a lifesaver, Paul.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using `gtExtras`. Unlike with `sparkline`, `gtExtras` charts are not interactive.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gtExtras)
library(gt)

df <- tibble(
  name = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 20),
  value = runif(40, min = -10, max = 10) %>% cumsum()
)


df %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  # for gtExtras' sparkline, a list of values needs to be provided
  summarise(chart = list(value), .groups = "drop") %>%
  gt() %>%
  gt_sparkline(chart)
```

[image]