# What is a good approach to add sparkline chart to an R gt table

Tags: r, gt

I am trying to use R `sparkline` with `gt`. My question is very similar to this one [Is it possible to use sparkline with gt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64479291/is-it-possible-to-use-sparkline-with-gt), but on top of simply using `sparkline` with `gt` as in the referenced question, I am trying to use it as part of the **summary row**. Below is the picture of what I have achieved so far. Here are my two questions:

- How can I remove the two grey lines that are printed as part of the `sparkline` chart in the summary row?
- Is there a better way to add `sparkline` to the summary row of a `gt` table?

[image]

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sparkline)
library(gt)

# toy data
df <- tibble(
  name = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 20),
  value = runif(40, min = -10, max = 10) %>% cumsum()
) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(
    index = row_number()
  ) %>% ungroup()

# preparing the data for the standard sparkline
regular_sparkline_df <- df %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise(
    chart = spk_chr(
      value,
      type="line"
    )
  )

# here I try to prepare the data for the summary row by getting the whole gt table and then removing the header
summary_row_sparkline_df <- df %>%
  group_by(index) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(value)) %>% ungroup() %>%
  summarise(
    chart = spk_chr(
      value,
      type="line"
    )
  ) %>%
  gt() %>%
  fmt_markdown(columns = vars(chart)) %>%
  gt:::as.tags.gt_tbl() %>%
  htmltools::attachDependencies(htmlwidgets::getDependency("sparkline")) %>%
  as.character() %>%
  gsub('<thead.+</thead>', "", .) # removing the header of the table

# building the html and adding dependencies
p_html <- regular_sparkline_df %>%
  gt() %>%
  fmt_markdown(columns = vars(chart)) %>%
  grand_summary_rows(
    columns = "chart",
    fns = list(Total = ~as.character(summary_row_sparkline_df)),
    formatter = fmt_markdown
  ) %>%
  gt:::as.tags.gt_tbl() %>%
  htmltools::attachDependencies(htmlwidgets::getDependency("sparkline"))

# seeing the table in the RStudio
print(p_html, browse = interactive())
```